# Multiple plural conditions translations

Tags: php, yaml, symfony5

I try to use the translator service in order to translate sentence containing 2 plural words see examples below :

```php
$countToBeDownloded = 2;
$allowedToDl = 0;

$countToBeDownloded1 = 15;
$allowedToDl1 = 4;

/*
 * Sentence : 
 *
 * `You tried to download {countToBeDownloded} image|images but your daily quota allow you to download only 
 * {allowedToDl} image|images`
 */

$this->translator->trans('mymessage', ['countToBeDownloded' => $countToBeDownloded, 'allowedToDl' => $allowedToDl]);

// mymessage output : You tried to download 2 images but your daily quota allow you to download only 0 image


$this->translator->trans('mymessage2', ['countToBeDownloded' => $countToBeDownloded1, 'allowedToDl' => $allowedToDl1]);

// mymessage output : You tried to download 15 images but your daily quota allow you to download only 4 images
```

As you can see I have to translate `image` twice using `countToBeDownloded` and `allowedToDl`.

There is my yaml translations file

```yaml
mymessage: |-
  {countToBeDownloded, plural,
      =1 {You tried to download # image but your daily quota allow you to download only {allowedToDl} images}
      other {You tried to download # images but your daily quota allow you to download only {allowedToDl} images}
  }
```

There is a way to achieve that ?

Comment: Translate this 2 parts of a sentence separately and then join?

Comment: Yeah sure but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without translate them separetly